# how to show on focusable item in listview 

Tags: android, listview, view

In my application i have used list view and custom cell which contain product name , image ,quantity and price now i want to implement that if use click on the product name then it should open a new quick action showing delete /edit . 
But problem is that when i m touching the listview cell, complete cell is showing focused. which is not desired. So please help me to implement this.

```
listviewObj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cart_items_listview);
listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(ShowCart.this);
listviewObj.setAdapter(listAdapter);
listviewObj.addFocusables(views, direction)
listviewObj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
    int position, long arg3) {
          Toast.makeText(ShowCart.this, "click on the position"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your CustomListAdapter code. it would be easy to get exactly and help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need `listviewObj.setItemsCanFocus(true);` in order for items inside listview cells to gain focus.

Answer (score 0):

you should implement listener on the cell item you want to work on as textview , Edit text or any kind of button  you have in your List Item layout   to show product name, image etc.

implement the Click-listener on cell items instead of whole listview item